# How to read the Screen Time status of an app programmatically on macOS?

Tags: macos, screen-time

***On a kids account with Screen Time activated, is there a way to detect once an app’s screen time is up by using command line tools?***

The app’s icon turns pale and an hourglass appears next to its name once time’s up. I know it’s possible to detect that using UI scripting in AppleScript. (E. g. by using triggers like the attribute “AXScreenTimeStatus” of an app’s icon appearing in the Dock, or the little hourglass behind the apps name after first opening its parent folder in Finder.)

I don’t only want to do this without having to show a folder or the Dock first, but I have to: *While one app is running full-screen, I need to have a script run invisibly that takes certain actions once it detects another app’s screen time is up (even if that app is not running).*

I’m on macOS Catalina.